# How to fill an empty DataFrame from associations discovered from Zoo Dataset

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, associations

I have many associations like the 2 associations given below

```
|------------------|
|Hair|Feathers|Type|
|------------------|  
|  1 |    0   |  1 |
|------------------|

|------------------|
|Hair| Eggs | Type |
|------------------|
| 1  |   0  |   1  |
```

And I have an empty DataFrame, which I want to fill with the values from the association rules by comparing the column names of the associations with the column name of the empty DataFrame. And putting the values in their respective column with every association value combination in single line. The output I desire is given below

```
|-----------------------------|
|Hair | Feathers | Eggs | Type|
|-----------------------------|
|  1  |     0    |      |   1 |
|  1  |          |   0  |   1 |
```

Any suggestions and comments will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just `pd.concat([df1, df2])`

Comment: What do you mean by `column name of the empty DataFrame`? You can achieve the output by what @coldspeed suggested.

Comment: @coldspeed thank you for the quick response. The concat function does the job but for each association it creates one DataFrame. So, for the above example, I have two concatenated DataFrames. Am I doing something wrong or shall I put all the code for you to see?

Comment: you say it does the job... so is there anything else?

Comment: Yes, it does the concatenation of both the DataFrames but for each association it creates one dataFrame. And I want it to be in a single dataFrame